# How do i configure Unity for One DbContext per web request

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container

I am using EF 6 and Unity 3.5 in an MVC application. I would like to know what is the proper way to configure DbContext using Unity.

As per my understanding this is more appropriate.

```
container.RegisterType<IdbContext, MyContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
```

Can anyone confirm if this is the right thing to do ?

Assuming that above code is right, do i need to dispose my context if i am injecting it in some ServiceLayer ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have seen this done a bunch of times. But when it is being used in a controller, make sure to override the Dispose() method

Comment: I am injecting a ServiceLayer in Controller. DbContext is being injected in ServiceLayer.  Do i still need to have Dispose in Controller ?

Comment: Well, I would implement iDisposable in service layer, and in controller override. Doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

I Prefer to use Constructor Injection

```
public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
       var container = new UnityContainer();

       ..... // others

       container.RegisterType<IMyDbContext, MyDbContext>(
        new TransientLifetimeManager(),
        new InjectionConstructor(infConfig.azure.dbConnectionString,
                                           DbValidationMode.Enabled,
                                           DbLazyLoadingMode.Disabled,
                                           DbAutoDetectMode.Enabled));

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);
```

Then in the controller I use

```
public class HomeController : ApiController (webApi) or Controller (MVC)
{
    IMyDbContext db;

    public HomeController(IMyDbContext db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetSomething()
    {
        var someEntities = db.SomeEntities.ToList();
        ... etc
    }
```

It will dispose of your context when the request instance dies.  It only has scope within your controller.